# \twocolumn with nested \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, two-column

When typesetting this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
    \includegraphics[width=12cm]{foo.png}
]
\end{document}
```

I get:

```
! Argument of \Gin@ii has an extra }.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.5    \includegraphics[width=12cm]
                                   {foo.png}
```

It works if I omit the `[width=12cm]`. What's a `\Gin@ii`, why does it have an extra `}`, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's nothing special to do: just enclose the `\includegraphics` in braces, so the `]` in its optional argument is not mistaken for the closing one of the optional argument to `\twocolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[%
    {\includegraphics[width=12cm]{foo.png}}%
]
\end{document}
```

Don't forget to protect the end of lines.